# Maven: How do I install mvnsh?

Tags: maven

I suspect I'm going about this the wrong way entirely.

I heard about [mvnsh](http://shell.sonatype.org/), and wanted to give it a try, to decrease the lag when I build.

But I'm completely clueless about how one would do that. I'm still learning maven, and drawing false parallels between `mvn` and tools like `gem`, `cabal`, or `cpan` is still biting me, so I'm not sure what I need to do to install a command line tool like `mvnsh`.

It doesn't seem to make sense to stick it as a dependency in some arbitrary project's `pom.xml`.

I downloaded `mvnsh-assembly-1.0.1.pom` from the download page on the theory that that was involved so far, but so far, nothing I've tried has worked.  `mvn install -f mvnsh-assembly-1.0.1.pom` downloaded a bunch of jars, then died.  `mvn artifact:install -f mvnsh-assembly-1.0.1.pom` downloaded more jars, then died.

I really have no idea what I'm doing here.  Should I even be using `mvn` to install `mvnsh`?

Comment: The questions is what kind of dependency you would like to put in your pom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just download the http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/maven/shell/dist/mvnsh-assembly/1.0.1/mvnsh-assembly-1.0.1-bin.zip or the .tar.gz archive depends on you OS unpack it and put the bin folder of the distribution to you PATH after that you can start mvnsh .

Comment: Yes, basically the mvnsh will give you a shell which will ensure that most of the plugins jars and other resources are loaded after your first execution of maven and not released unlike between 2 mvn runs